# Issue using let keyword in EF Core query

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want to do this query using EF Core 7 in C# :

```
var query = (from t in _dbContext.Domaines
                             join tick1 in _dbContext.Tickets on t.Iddomaine equals tick1.Iddomaine
                             join etatticket in _dbContext.Etattickets on tick1.Idticket equals etatticket.Idticket
                             join etat in _dbContext.Etats on etatticket.Idetat equals etat.Idetat
                             join contact in _dbContext.Contacts on tick1.Idcontact equals contact.Idcontact
                             group new { t, tick1, etatticket, etat, contact } by new { t.Iddomaine, tick1.Idticket, contact.Nom, contact.Prenom } into g
                             let LibelleCurrentEtatTicket = (from e in _dbContext.Etattickets
                                                             join et in _dbContext.Etats on e.Idetat equals et.Idetat
                                                             where g.Key.Idticket == e.Idticket
                                                             group e by new { et.Intituleetat, e.Dateaction } into g2
                                                             let maxDateAction = g2.Max(x => x.Dateaction)
                                                             where g2.Key.Dateaction == maxDateAction
                                                             select g2.Key.Intituleetat).ToList()
                             select new TicketSpecifique
                             {
                                 
                                 Idticket = g.Key.Idticket,
                                 
                                 Intitule = g.FirstOrDefault().tick1.Intitule,
                                 Iddomaine = g.Key.Iddomaine,
                                 IntituleDomaine = g.FirstOrDefault().t.Intituledomaine,
                                 IntituleEtatTicket = LibelleCurrentEtatTicket.FirstOrDefault(),
                                 NomContact = g.Key.Nom,
                                 PrenomContact = g.Key.Prenom,
                                 Suiviinterne = g.FirstOrDefault().tick1.Suiviinterne,
                                 Suiviclient = g.FirstOrDefault().tick1.Suiviclient,
                                 
                             }).OrderBy(x => x.Idticket);
```

When I want to use `query.ToList()`, I have the following issue :

[image]

I tried to search on the internet and some topics talked about a bug in EF. Is that true or anyone as an answer about that issue ?

Comment: The real issue here is the attempt to use EF Core to write what is essentially raw SQL (with nested subqueries), instead of using relations and navigation properties. If `Country` has a `Tickets` property, and `Ticket` has a `Countries` property, EF itself will generate JOINs as needed. And since EF Core 7, you won't even have to create a `CountryTicket` bridge entity to connect the two.

Comment: The job of ORMs like EF is to give the impression of working with *objects* instead of tables. EF's job is to give you a country with all its tickets without you having to JOIN anything, or load individual objects. ORMs are *not* meant for complex reporting queries. It's much better to create a view or stored procedure with the complex query and map the view's results to objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `ToList` from the `let` subquery. `ToList` is a client-side feature, it's not supported to use it inside an EF Core query.

```cs
....
    let LibelleCurrentEtatTicket = (
        from e in _dbContext.Etattickets
        join et in _dbContext.Etats on e.Idetat equals et.Idetat
        where g.Key.Idticket == e.Idticket
        group e by new { et.Intituleetat, e.Dateaction } into g2
        let maxDateAction = g2.Max(x => x.Dateaction)
        where g2.Key.Dateaction == maxDateAction
        select g2.Key.Intituleetat
    )
....
```

I can't say for sure without knowing your data, but this code could probably do with a good dose of window functions. These are not supported by EF Core, so you are probably best off doing this in raw SQL.